# Conditions for Nilpotency of inverse image of homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\varphi : G \to L$ be a homomorphism and $U \le L$. Under what conditions is $\varphi^{-1}(U)$ nilpotent, if $U$ is nilpotent?

And a closely related question. If $UN/N$ is a nilpotent subgroup of $G/N$, what could be said about the nilpotency of $UN$ or $U$?

Comment: So you mean the property of a subgroup being nilpotent within the overgroup. Does $H\subseteq G$ being nilpotent mean the sequence $[G,H]$, $[G,[G,H]]$, $[G,[G,[G,H]]]\cdots$ eventually terminates at $1$? If so, then my original response seems to still apply, since we can consider the trivial group a nilpotent subgroup of itself, right?

Comment: You are right, my initial question was totally wrongly worded. Sorry, I rephrased it. I confused the relation between two groups, that could be preserved by inverse images, like being normal in another groups, with a property of the group itself, like being nilpotent.

Comment: @whacka: I mean a group $G$ is nilpotent iff $U < N_G(U)$ for each proper subgroup $U < G$, which is equivalent with most properties mentioned here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will write some lemmas related to nilpotency and quotient;
Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$,

**Lemma:** If $N\leq \Phi(G)$ and $G/N$ is nilpotent then $G$ is nilpotent.

**Lemma:** If $N\leq Z(G)$ and $G/N$ is nilpotent then $G$ is nilpotent.

**Lemma:** If $N$ and $G/N'$ is nilpotent then $G$ is nilpotent.